# How can i change the content type insdie my enterprise wiki site collection

Tags: content-type, page-layout, publishing-site, enterprise-wiki

I am a bit confused on how i can change the default content type for my enterprise wiki site collection. now i have created a new content type named "test" and define that its parent should be the "Enterprise Wiki Page" content type, as follow:-

[image]

Now i want my custom CT to be used inside all the wiki pages, but can not find a way to do so, and i faced the following 3 problems-

1. when i access the pages library inside my Enterprise wiki SC, i have noted that the "Error Page" is the default content type. although when i create a new wiki page it will be based on the "Enterprise Wiki Page" CT and not on the default "Error Page".. so how is this done, i mean new pages are not based on the default CT.

[image]

2. now i added my custom content type named "Test", and i removed the built-in "Enterprise wiki page" CT from the library, then i set the test content type as the defualt CT.
   but now when i create a new wiki page its content type will be "Project Page" and not my custom CT ?
3. how i can create a new page layout to be based on my custom CT ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This isn't set at the library level, it's set at the site level. Site Settings > Page layouts and site templates and add the layout to the page layouts list and seperately set the New Page Default Settings to your template.

Comment: can you please advice more , now i went to "Site setting >> Master page & Page layout". then i upload a copy of the enterprisewiki page layout. but how i can define that this page layout should be based on the new content type "test" ? & how i can set this page layout to be used when creating new wiki pages , is this set using Design Manager?

Comment: While you can change the group that it lies under on the Site Content Types page (whatever level you have created this at, whether its root or a subsite), that is strictly an organizational detail. 

The Parent Content Type for a type is set when the content is created and changing would be messy and would involve either a database or Powershell script. If you have to change the Parent Content Type, you're better off starting over.

Comment: Just to be clear, though, page layouts do not need to be custom content types unless you're looking to create additional meta data around the page itself (such as check in notes, content owners, other random information that can't be kept at the page data level itself.

Comment: yes i know that i do not have to create a new CT for the new page layout . but in my case i have added many columns to the page layout , where i added 5 new meta data columns similar to the built-in "Wiki Category" column.  so i do not want to add them directly to the built-in "enterprise wiki page " CT , so i created a new CT that have its parent = the built-in EnterpriseWiki Page CT and i added the 5 new site columns to the new cT. so my question is how i can create a new Page layout and define that this page layout should use the new CT and set it as the defualt page layout ?

Comment: When you're creating the content type (as your screenshot above has you doing), you select a content type for the Parent. It has to be one that inherits from the Page content type. Select one of the ones from the Page content type category (probably Enterprise Wiki) and set the group to be Page. Then your page will show up as inheriting from Page. 

Then create a new page layout (Design Manager > Page Layout > Create or SP Designer > Page Layouts > New Page Layouts) and select the content type you created.

Comment: i did not understand you reply, now i have created a new CT that have the "Enterprise Wiki page" CT as its parent ,,i name it "test" as shown in the picture, is this correct ? then then inside my site collection I went to "Site Setting >> Master pages and page layouts " i download a copy of the built-in "EnterpriseWiki.aspx" page layout. i rename the file inside my PC, and i upload the renamed file, where i set its CT to be "test". after that i went to "site setting >> Page Layout and Site Template Settings"and is set the new page layout as the default page layout. are these steps valid?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you on?